# ScreenUpdating = False not working

Tags: excel, vba

I know there are lots of threads relating to this topic, like don't use "Select" or "Activate" or set it to false if you need to use it. I set it to False every time I use "select" or "activate", but it still not working, please help!!

```
Sub Forecast()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    'Application.StatusBar = "Please be patient..."

    Dim Rating As Variant, sht As Worksheet, LastRecordRow As Long, i As Integer, LastRow As Long

    Rating = InputBox("Please Provide Weather Rating (Any Number Between 1 and 4)", "Input Needed")

    If Rating < 0 Or Rating > 4 Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Value, Please Enter A Valid Number! (1~4)", , "Alert!!!"
        Exit Sub
    Else

        For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name = "Forecast" Then
            sht.Range("a1") = ""
        Else
            LastRecordRow = sht.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
            sht.Range("I1:O1").EntireColumn.Delete
            Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", sht.Range("$B$1", "$B" & LastRecordRow), _
            sht.Range("$C$1", "$C" & LastRecordRow), False, True, , sht.Range("$I$1") _
            , False, False, False, False, , False
            PVTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B2", "B" & LastRecordRow))
            ImpTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("D2", "D" & LastRecordRow))
            sht.Range("B" & LastRecordRow + 1) = PVTotal
            sht.Range("D" & LastRecordRow + 1) = ImpTotal
            sht.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            sht.Range("A1").Select
        End If
        Next sht

        Worksheets("Forecast").Activate

        i = 1

        ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i + 2, Range("H" & i + 2).End(xlDown)).EntireRow.Delete

        Do While i <= ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
            RowForSum = Worksheets(i).Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row
            With ActiveSheet
                .Cells(i + 2, 2).Value = Worksheets(i).Name
                .Cells(i + 2, 3).Value = Worksheets(i).Range("J17")
                .Cells(i + 2, 4).Value = Worksheets(i).Range("J18")
                .Cells(i + 2, 5).Value = Rating
                .Cells(i + 2, 6).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, 3).Value + ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, 4) * Rating
                If Worksheets(i).Range("B183").Value = 0 Then
                    .Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = 0
                Else
                    .Cells(i + 2, 7).Value = Worksheets(i).Range("D" & RowForSum).Value / Worksheets(i).Range("B" & RowForSum).Value
                End If
                    .Cells(i + 2, 8).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, 6).Value * ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 2, 7)
            End With
            i = i + 1
        Loop

        LastRow = ActiveSheet.Range("B2").End(xlDown).Row

        a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("F3", "F" & LastRow))
        b = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(ActiveSheet.Range("H3", "H" & LastRow))

        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("F" & LastRow + 1).Value = a
            .Range("F" & LastRow + 1).Offset(0, -4).Value = "Total"
            .Range("H" & LastRow + 1).Value = b
            .Range("A1").Select
            .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With

        Dim rng2 As Range
        For Each rng2 In ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))
            If rng2 = "Forecast" Then
                rng2.EntireRow.Delete
            Else
                If rng2 = "Total" Then rng2.EntireRow.Font.Bold = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How is it not working, what's the error or the wrong behaviour you're seeing?

Comment: the screen still is flickering until it gave me the results

Comment: It's possible your setting is overridden by calling into some method, maybe the `Regress` in the Analysis ToolPak. Try putting the following statement: `Debug.Print Application.ScreenUpdating` throughout your code and, after your routine has finished, check to see if at any point it changes value. Also, screen updating won't work if you're debugging/stepping through the code. Not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: djikay, thank you a lot for this, now I'm able to identify where is the bad guy messing up my setting, and you're right, it is the regress that make the setting back to TRUE. My next question is, even now I put App.ScreenUpdating = False before and after the regress statement, all screens are still flickering, any suggestions on that? Thank you a lot!

Comment: Try to add more `Debug.Print Application.ScreenUpdating` throughout the rest of your code. Does the value change to `True` anywhere? There may be something else messing up the setting. Also, I read somewhere that having any watches active might cause a problem, so try removing any watches you may have and see if that makes any difference. I'm really struggling to find anything else to suggest.

Comment: I'd also suggest you try setting: `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` at the start and back to automatic at the end. If you're not using any worksheet events (or any events for that matter), you can turn those off too: `Application.EnableEvents = False`.

Comment: djikay, thank you a lot for all your suggestions. I do see somewhere about the "watch" thing, but my code don't have them. Actually it's the regression code that make my screen flickering, as every time there is a regression run and result posted onto the same worksheet as where the source data resides, it's like that worksheet is activated, causing the screen flickering. I tried the xlcalculationmanual, but no luck. Not sure if there is a way that even if I post the regression result the worksheet won't be activated.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue. Workbook which used `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` became slow in Excel 2016 and flickered while running VBA that updated worksheets.

Using message boxes and `Debug.Print` statements I tracked it down to a loop that updated cell contents using code like:

```
Dim rowCounter As Integer
For rowCounter = 1 To numberOfEmployees
    'Do some work
    If (someCondition) Then
        startCell.offset(rowCounter).Value = ""
    Else 
        startCell.offset(rowCounter).Value = "something else"
    End If
Next rowCounter
```

If I replaced the following line

```
startCell.offset(rowCounter).Value = ""
```

with either of

```
startCell.offset(rowCounter).Value = "anything except empty"
```

or

```
startCell.offset(rowCounter).ClearContents
```

then the flickering stopped and the time to execute the loop went from a few seconds to much less than 1s.

I am not sure why this worked.

So if any of your cells in the loop return empty string, you could try using either of these lines.

Comment: but i need to find the first empty line 
is there a way to tackle this issue

Answer (score 0):

Do not put in the same procedure / module / function it disabling and enabling.
Leave Application.ScreenUpdating = False as needed and place Application.ScreenUpdating = true outside this procedure / module / function. For me it is the only way that really works.

Comment: Try insert in new function. Call this function and resume your code and outher function to true display.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Thanks to this discussion I solved the problem by putting Application.ScreenUpdating = False both before and after the Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress" etc. statement:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Regress", sht.Range("$B$1", "$B" & LastRecordRow), _
sht.Range("$C$1", "$C" & LastRecordRow), False, True, , sht.Range("$I$1") _
, False, False, False, False, , False

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Has to be that procedure, my app worked fine until I used that procedure.