# ScreenUpdating = False stopped working in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, screenupdating

I have a sub that starts with

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

and it worked perfectly fine. Now I added after this a line to call a different sub from a different module in this same file. Now the above line of code oddly does not work. Now ScreenUpdating stays True after the above line is run. Still does not work if I move it to after the other Sub call. I have verified this using F8 and hovering over the "ScreenUpdating" and it says True, and there is much flickering while the program runs.

Why does this line not work anymore? I read that some people have a glitch with ScreenUpdating within Subs where a different Sub is called. This is my situation.

To clarify, the issue is not that the ScreenUpdating actually toggles to False and then later switches back to True. The issue is that the above line of code completely does nothing. It is as if VBA is not reading it at all. It is almost certainly some glitch and not an issue with the code.

How do I edit this so that the above line works and the flickering goes away? Or some other workaround? Some way to call other Subs without this glitch occuring?

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067667/screenupdating-false-not-working

Comment: Do you have `Option Explicit` ? Try `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: You may get flickering if you have selects, especially if you are selecting different workbooks or worksheets.

Comment: Check the Sub you're calling for ScreenUpdating = True.

Comment: Why don't you share both subs?